# Issue getting and storing memory address in array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

So, I'm having a bit of pointer issues.
I'm writing a function that stores memory addresses in a[].
These memory addresses point to actual data values in b[].
I'm having trouble getting the memory address from b to store in a.

```
// Assume these are initialized to 0 outside of this snippet
char a[100];
char b[100];
b[0] = 42;  // Some value for us to use

int* a_ptr = (int*)&a[0];    // Store the address of a[0] in a_ptr
int* b_ptr = (int*)&b[0];    // Store the address of b[0] in b_ptr

*a_ptr = (int)&b_ptr;   // PROBLEM LINE.  The first four bytes of a[] 
                        // should contain the memory address of b[0].
                        // However, it does not.  Here are the debugger values:
                        // a_ptr = 0x00429148
                        // b_ptr = 0x00429151
                        // a[0] SHOULD be 0x00429151, but it is instead 0x0012fe4c.
```

Is there some trick I need to do to get 0x00429151 to be stored at a[0..3]?

Comment: "Should contain the memory address of b[0]"? If you want them to contain "the memory address of b[0]", why are you forcing the address of `b_ptr` there instead of address of `b[0]`?

Answer (score 4):

```
*a_ptr = (int) b_ptr;
```

*updated per comments*

Comment: `a_ptr` is already an `int *`. No need to cast it. `*a_ptr = (int) b_ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind...it's obviously too late.

To solve, change

```
 *a_ptr = (int)&b_ptr;
```

to

```
*a_ptr = (int)b_ptr;
```

Comment: Why are you even going via `int`? Why `int *` when the actual objects are `char`? `char **a_ptr = (char **)&a[0]; *a_ptr = &b[0];` would make more sense.

Comment: The reason is that I need the memory address of b[0], not the value.  A pointer won't fit inside of a char as it is generally 4 bytes and a char is 1.  Int is 4 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Yikes - what a mess.  If a and b are arrays of char, then you don't want to create int*s to them... an int is a bigger memory area than a char, and when you read you'll pick up other values beside the char and end up with an effectively random value.  If you try to store to the int*, you'll clobber the char's value (possibly with an unintended value), while clobbering several values around it.

It's a very good idea not to use C-style casts (e.g. "(int*)") while learning C++.  If you use static_cast<> the compiler can tell you when you've made a big mistake.

So, what you want is:

```
  char* p_a = &a[0];
  char* p_b = &b[0];
  *p_a = *p_b;  // copy
```

Comment: "you'll pick up other values beside the char".  This is exactly what I want.  These are effectively byte arrays storing an arbitrary number of types - not single chars.  Think of b[0] as a buffer.  If I want to store an int at b[0], then it would use b[0]-b[3].  Which is what I want.  That is why I need the address of b[0].  I can return the address of b[0], which is stored at a[0], so tht the calling function (which knows the type) knows how many bytes to read/write to b[];

Answer (score 0):

Though there are better ways to do this, this probably is the closest to your approach

```
   int main(){
    char *a[100];        // not char but char * 
    char b[100]; 
    b[0] = 42;          // Some value for us to use 

    char** a_ptr = (char **)&a[0];    // Store the address of a[0] in a_ptr 
    char* b_ptr = (char*)&b[0];       // Store the address of b[0] in b_ptr 

    *a_ptr = b_ptr;
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, a and be must remain as is per the assignment.